# After update of chrome and cypress realHover is not working

Tags: cypress

Can anyone confirm that plugin cypress-real-events is not working any more with Chrome version 100 and higher?

Comment: You may want to check on the github repo itself to check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Chrome version, but it doesn't work with Cypress 10.